# 7-Zip rename root folder in a zip from command line

Tags: command-line, 7zip

I’m using 7-Zip to create a .zip file from command line.
I have this directory structure D:\TEST\ROOT_FOLDER\ now I want to create zip file that include all files under ROOT_FOLDER and also that the root folder name in the zip will be ROOT instead of ROOT_FOLDER.

Currently I set the working directory to D:\TEST and then run this, from what I see **rn** command is only used to rename files not folders, so it there a way to do what I want ?

```
7z.exe a -r D:\\TEST.zip ROOT_FOLDER\*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rn` ("Rename files in archive") command after you've created the archive:

```
7z.exe a -r D:\TEST.zip ROOT_FOLDER\* 
7z.exe rn D:\TEST.zip ROOT_FOLDER ROOT
```

The `--help` flag gives you information about available commands:

```
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...] [@listfile]

<Commands>
  a : Add files to archive
  b : Benchmark
  d : Delete files from archive
  e : Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
  h : Calculate hash values for files
  i : Show information about supported formats
  l : List contents of archive
  rn : Rename files in archive
  t : Test integrity of archive
  u : Update files to archive
  x : eXtract files with full paths
```